# Nginx caching headers by file type

Tags: caching, nginx, http-headers

I want to set caching headers for files delivered by nginx. Is there a way to set caching headers for certain files based by their type? E.g. I want to set caching headers to all js files but not other files. I don't want to set headers based on the location where the files are.

Comment: You could use [Headers More module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule). It could set headers based on response content type.

Comment: And how do I set the headers per file type? I don't have a specific location for cacheable files and another for those where I don't want to add caching headers.

Comment: `more_set_headers -t application/x-javascript 'Cache-Control: max-age=31536000'`

Comment: write this please as an answer. Then I'll be able to give you an 'up' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Headers More](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule) module. It has option to set headers based on response content type.

```
more_set_headers -t application/x-javascript 'Cache-Control: max-age=31536000'
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old but a map and expires would automatically do that with Cache-Control Header without any extra modules, and you can still add public or private via add_header

```html
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
   
    application/pdf               42d;
    application/zip               42d;
    application/x-7z-compressed   42d;
    application/x-rar-compressed  42d;

    application/octet-stream  1M;

    application/javascript    3M;
    text/css                  3M;
    ~image/                   3M;
    ~video/                   3M;
    ~audio/                   3M;
    ~text/                    1d; # html/php

    default                  off;
}

expires $expires;
```